# testing simple functions in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am building a simple React app and trying to test some functions that perform some logic within the components. I have cypress tests but I'm now trying to use jest.

This particular function needs to return the most frequent string. The function currently works, and is like so...

```
favourite(item) {
    return item.sort((a,b) =>
        item.filter(v => v===a).length
        - item.filter(v => v===b).length
    ).pop();
}
```

and my test (not currently working) looks like this...

```
import React from "react";
import { create } from "react-test-renderer";
import ShoppingCart from "../components/ShoppingCart";

describe("most frequent shopping item", () => {
    test("returns the most frequent string in an array", () => {
        const component = create(<ShoppingCart />);
        const instance = component.getInstance();
        items = ["eggs", "jam", "jam", "milk", "bread" ]
        expect(instance.favourite(items)).toBe("jam");
    });
});
```

My test is reading the props of the component but gets:

> cannot read property 'length' of undefined

I call `.length` on the array in the component.

Any suggestions on how I can test simple functions in components would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Separately define the function inside your component file (but outside the component), export it and test it, without the need for a component to be instantiated inside the test case. Of course, you can use it inside the component as well.

```
export const favourite = function(item){
    return item.sort((a,b) =>
    item.filter(v => v===a).length
    - item.filter(v => v===b).length
    ).pop();
}
```

Then in your test you can do

```
import { favourite } from 'path/to/file';

describe('favourite', () => {

    it('should return the item that occurs most frequently', () => {

        const items = ["eggs", "jam", "jam", "milk", "bread" ]
        expect(favourite(items)).toBe("jam");

    });

});
```

Comment: thanks very much. and in the test file what comes before favourite / what do i actually call that function on? would it be expect(this.favourite(items)).toBe etc. etc.?

Comment: No, since you import the function directly you can call it like you would any other import. I've updated my answer to give you a concrete example. Also, I completely missed that you did not assign items to a `const`, `let` or `var` in your original example. That can also be a reason why it doesn't work.

Comment: thanks very much. i've just exported them and tested them for now. appreciate it :)